# How to stop WebPack from including CSS file in the html even though it is already included in the produced js file

Tags: css, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using WebPack to build a chrome extension. I import the css file in the popup.js file and it correctly styles my page but bundler also inserts the css file to the html which is unnecessary if I know correctly since it is injected to the output js file. Because the css file is included in the hmtl, I get a "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". I want to know how to exclude the CSS file from the html and basically dont have the following line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup-styles.css" />
```

This is my webpack.config.js file.

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        popup: "./src/popup.js",
        background: "./src/background.js",
        content: "./src/content.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/popup.html",
            filename: "popup.html",
            chunks: ["popup"],
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [{ from: "public" }],
        }),
    ],
};
```